# Datastax Enterprise - Amazon M3.Xlarge Machines

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

Does anyone know how to use Datastax enterprise (using opscenter) in a cluster using amazon ec2 M3.Xlarge machines?
When I have tried to use these type of instances (that use ssd) I got the following error:
Launching instances failed.Invalid node size specified

If I use M1.Xlarge it works fine.

Answer (score 8):

This is a problem with Opscenter itself.  This should be fixed in the next major release of Opscenter.  The OPSC-3233 internal ticket tracks this fix, and may be used to refer to this problem in support emails and release notes.